# Communicating between Android App and C# server with public IP address

Tags: c#, android, tcp, ip

I have a server running on C# application. And a client on an Android app,
These two can communicate only if they are on the same network and only with Private addresses 192.168.1.*
How do i make this work for public IP address.
As in, 
The Android App can communicate from outside the home network also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you will almost never be able to directly connect your phone to your computer with TCP over the internet is that usually one or both of your devices is behind one or several firewalls, gateways, routers, proxies, or is [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)ted.

A device will only be able to initiate a connection **to** a listening server that has a public IP address. For example, although your home computer is most likely behind one of the above, you can open http://www.stackoverflow.com because the StackOverflow web server has a public IP.

The same goes for your phone. In most cases, your phone's ISP (mobile provider) won't assign your phone a public IP, and even if it does, it will likely block or filter most packets, making it very difficult to use the phone as the listening server.

**What are your options?**

**Port forwarding**. Forwarding your home's access router to your PC is a good option for testing. (It gets more complicated if you expect to run a service of some sort with thousands of clients.

With port forwarding, you first need to make sure you can configure  your router (I, for instance, don't have access to it in my building). If you do have access to the configuration of your router, set up a port forward (e.g. anything that goes to port 12345 on your router is forwarded to 12345 on your PC). Next, determine the router's public IP (http://www.wimi.com). Finally, try connecting from your phone using the router's IP. Remember that your router's public IP address is most likely not static, and may change at any given moment.

**Use a middle man**. A common option is to use a publicly available server to keep the two in touch. Using a web server and regular HTTP or HTTPS connections is the safest (i.e. the least likely to get blocked along the way). So, for example:

- Phone to Middle man: Do I have any messages?
- Middle man answers: Nope, sorry.
- PC to Middle man: Say "Hi!" to Phone please.
- Middle-person answers: Ok, I will.
- Phone to Middle man: Do I have any messages?
- Middle man answer: Yup, PC says "Hi!"

Notice that each connection is initiated by either the PC or the Phone. The Middle man can answers queries, but it can't start connections by itself (since neither the Phone nor the PC are accessible).

Although I'd say this is probably the simplest way to get messages from one to the other, there is quite a bit of overhead and latency won't be great. There are, of course alternatives if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, or at the very least your home router is configurable. Look at [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) and [SSH tunnels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol).

**Get a static public IP**. Complicated and expensive for IPv4, but it solves most of your problems, especially if you're thinking of running some sort of service.

Comment: Most of the IP's out there are public, If you're working behind a router, Make sure to forward the wanted port (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to your computer.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but [according to this article](http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/getting-a-free-public-ipv6-using-it-on-ubuntu/), you can get a public IPv6 for free. Static public IPv4 addresses are usually harder to come by. Some countries don't give them out at all anymore.

Comment: I've edited to expand on port forwarding (which I agree with Shani would be the best option for developing, assuming the OP can access his/her router), and clarified that it's _static_ public _IPv4_ addresses that are complicated and expensive.

Comment: Also, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072805/best-communication-strategy-between-android-client-and-net-c-sharp-server